# How to remove view on the child's parent? android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I have a button that displays an alert dialog when its clicked. 
I create the view for the alert dialog in the onCreate method of my activity.
The code for that is right here:

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    view = factory.inflate(R.layout.grade_result, null);
```

When I push the button for the first time, the dialog displays the way I want it, but when I push it a second time it throws this exception.

11-28 00:35:58.066: E/AndroidRuntime(30348): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

My code for the method that displays the AlertDialog when the button is pushed is right here:

```
public void details(View v){
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setView(view);
    alert.setMessage("Details About Your Grades")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Inflating the view that should be set within the Builder of the AlertDialog worked for me :

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // inflating view out of the onClick() method does not work
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final ViewGroup viewGroup= (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);

            Dialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
                    .setView(viewGroup)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with alert dialog. First time I inflated a view and second time I wanted to display a message.
If you display the alert dialog once then you inflate the view and the dialog is cached. If you display it second time you get the error  IllegalStateException:"call removeView() on child's parent first"

I solved this issue by removing the view that I inflated on first click and displayed the message on second click.
-remove the view or message every time before you inflate or create a message.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(null).setMessage(null);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(yourView).setMessage(yourMessage);
```

I modified Your code and it work's fine with me.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
mView = factory.inflate(R.layout.grade_result, null);

public void details(View v){
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setView(null).setMessage(null);
    alert.setView(mView);
    alert.setMessage("Details About Your Grades")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    alert.show(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

It says that your "view" was connected to parent. It's happend when you called .setView(view). If i'm right - alertDialog class gives parent for your view. It is basics for android. ViewGroup may have a lot of child View's. I had similar problem.
So, you can try this insinde onClick:

```
ViewGroup vGroup = view.getParent();
vGroup.removeView(view);
// And right after that - close dialog
dialog.dismiss();
```

It helped me, I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProductsListAfterFilter.this);
alert.setTitle("Добавить продукт в корзину?");
alert.setMessage("Введите количество: ");

// Set an EditText view to get user input
final EditText input = new EditText(ProductsListAfterFilter.this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        int value = 0 ;
    try {
            value = Integer.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
    }
    catch (Exception err){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Введите число", 100).show();
    }
    //insertValue(value,st1,st2,st3,st4);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value = "+value, 100).show();
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog.cancel();
    }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
        dialog.cancel();
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});


final AlertDialog alertd = alert.create();
alertd.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use alert.create(); then alertd.dismiss(); to destroy dialog

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog alertd = alert.create();

        alert.setTitle("Title");
        alert.setMessage("Messaage");

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
              dialog.cancel();
              alertd.dismiss();
          }
        });
```

Comment: it didnt work, i still get the same problem and sometimes the dialog doesnt even show up

Comment: it doesn't show up simply because he doesn't have called show() on the alert dialog. 

But your problem is far more complex, if you can call dismiss() it's very simple, the problem is that the dialog can be hidden also by touching the rest of the screen, and in that case you don't click any button, so you're not able to call dismiss(). I think you should use a listener that will catch the hiding of the dialog and call dismiss on it, or something like that

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setView(view);
alert.setMessage("Details About Your Grades")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
AlertDialog alertdialog = alert.create();
alertdialog .show()
```

Answer (score -2):

you can set View to null before setting the view in the dialog.
just like this:

```
alert.setView(null);
alert.setView(view);
```

It will always set view to null before setting it again.